# Glm VECTORIZE2_VEC redefined XCode warning

Tags: c++, xcode, glm-math

I keep getting warnings only in XCode about some macros in glm being redefined. it's not a huge issue but I find warnings annoying.

If I put a #ifndef block over the culprit macros but then the entire system wont work? I include them in a static lib which is linked to an app which also includes them. I though this might be the issue so I removed it from one of the two to see if it helped. It didn't.

This warning does not appear when using mingw g++ on windows but it does in Xcode 4. I am using glm version 0.9.3.4.

Warnings:

```
"VECTORIZE2_VEC" redefined
This is the location of the previous definition
```

This is repeated hundreds of times.

Culprit code (taken from glm file _vectorize.hpp):

```
#define VECTORIZE2_VEC(func) \
template <typename T> \
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER detail::tvec2<T> func( \
    detail::tvec2<T> const & v) \
{ \
    return detail::tvec2<T>( \
        func(v.x), \
        func(v.y)); \
}
```

There are a few other macros very similar to this one.

Comment: Show the warnings and related code, please

Comment: What GLM are you talking about? There are *many* things named "GLM".

Comment: opengl maths library http://glm.g-truc.net/

Comment: when you put #ifndef VECTORIZE2_VEC ... #endif around your #define, what do you mean "The entire system wont work"? It wont compile or does it crashes, etc? Are you sure the signature of the VECTORIZE2_VEC macro is the same? I mean are you passing the same args as the previously defined macro?

Comment: glm gives an error from another file and wont compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above, it appears as though you have 3 options:

1. Just live with the compilation warnings
2. Change the location of your VECTORIZE2_VEC macro definition with respect to the #include's, since the other definition of VECTORIZE2_VEC has not wrapped it in an #ifndef (and this is causing the compilation warning)
3. Consider if you really need to #define it again, considering its already defined.

Option 1 is ok, but if you have a "no compilation warning" requirement, which is actually a good thing, then you'll have to go with option 2 (which in my opinion could become difficult to maintain) or 3.

To implement option 2, you will need to define the macro ***after*** the include where it is originally defined, but ***before*** the other #include's that need it. This may not be possible, if you get the original definition and the compilation error by just #including one file, in which case you're out of luck.

Assuming file1.h has the original VECTORIZE2_VEC definition, and file2.h needs the definition and causes a compilation error in its absence, the following could fix the problem and be error and warning free:

```
#include <file1.h>

#ifdef VECTORIZE2_VEC 
  #undef VECTORIZE2_VEC 
#endif
#define VECTORIZE2_VEC(func) ....

#include <file2.h>

// ...
```